# Give me any example of imprimitive and primitive Dirichlet characters

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Can you give me any example about the induced modulus of an imprimitive Dirichlet charcter, and an example of a primitive Dirichlet character? My book does not have any appropriate examples.

Comment: I want you to explain what you want to get.

Comment: if $a(n)$ is a discrete logarithm modulo $p$ a prime (i.e. there is a $g$ such that $g^{a(n)} \equiv n \bmod p$) then for any fixed integer $1 \le c \le p-1$ : $\chi(n) = 0$ if $p | n$, otherwise $\chi(n) = e^{2 i \pi c \, a(n) / (p-1)}$   is a Dirichlet character modulo $p$, and there are no others

Comment: this is why you can really think to the Dirichlet characters (modulo $p$) as being the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) on $n \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with the indexes permuted (by the discrete logarithm)

Comment: Apostol *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, pg. 169, Examples 1 and 2.